# What are those polygons on the Garmin avionics navigation display?

Tags: navigation, avionics, feature-identification, display

I'm not pilot yet, just an enthusiast having some fun in MSFS2020.

What do those colored lines mean in Garmin avionics?

[image: Screenshot msfs2020]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The various lines you see are used to demark certain aspects of the airspace such as controlled airspace (of differing classes) including terminal manouvering areas, restricted areas, military no-fly zones etc.

You get a slightly clearer picture (if you're used to reading sectional aeronautical charts) by looking at the [real thing](https://skyvector.com/?ll=-22.98361,-43.376943&chart=301&zoom=3) rather than a display on a simulated GPS.

[image]

- The blue area to the north-west  appears to be SBR-301 which is a restricted area
- The magenta area extending mostly North and North-East is the various areas of controlled airspace protecting traffic arriving and departing the various airfields shown to the south
- The orange line I'm not too sure about.

Related: [What do these polygons mean on VFR charts?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/25828)